# Deployment life-cycle events AWS code deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy, aws-code-deploy-appspec

I have a react application and using AWS CodeDeploy to deploy the changes. Deployment is working fine with ECS but the `Install` lifecycle event takes too much time. According to the AWS Documentation:

```
Install – During this deployment lifecycle event, the CodeDeploy agent copies the revision files from the temporary location to the final destination folder. This event is reserved for the CodeDeploy agent and cannot be used to run scripts.
```

I want to debug why it's taking too long for this specific step.